# Network Related Apache 2.4 403 Authz Error AH01630

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, linux-networking, mod-authz-host

I've never seen this style of behavior before. If I access this site on most networks it works. However if I am on-site of the client I cannot pull up the site.

- TWC Home, works fine.
- ATT Cell Data, works fine.
- Pingdom tests, work fine.
- *TWC @Work, pulls the error below.*

> [authz_core:error] [pid 21185] [client 108.162.237.68:41489] AH01630:
>   client denied by server configuration:
>   /srv/www/homemadechocolategifts.com/public_html/

Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName homemadechocolategifts.com
DocumentRoot /srv/www/homemadechocolategifts.com/public_html/
<IfModule mpm_itk_module>
AssignUserId www_tsc www_tsc
</IfModule>
    <Directory / >
            Options All
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
ErrorLog /srv/www/logs/homemadechocolategifts.com.error.log
CustomLog /srv/www/logs/homemadechocolategifts.com.access.log combined
```

I run 8 other vhosts on this server and they all can be pulled up from the site I am at. The only one I can't is the one above.

I'm not really sure where to look to even resolve such an issue that seems bound up in how a network accesses it. Why would I get a permissions oriented error one place, but not another place? Usually, it's a ubiquitous config error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Far more straight-forward an answer. Banned host.

```
[Tue May 10 14:12:15.367970 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 4064] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 173.245.56.206:21186] AH01626: authorization result of Require not ip 172.72.136.128: neutral, referer: http://homemadechocolategifts.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=toplevel_page_itsec_logs
```

Debug mode turned on. I had checked whitelists, cleared most block lists, one left untouched, one was the culprit. Check your wordpress security plugins for an errant host ban. I can only guess that someone tried to whitelist their IP address and ended up putting it in the ban list. How it wasn't noticed immediately is a puzzle but one for another day.